# Parse multiple JSON files

Tags: json, angularjs

I have two JSON files

```
{
    "teams":
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Brazil"
        },
{
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Argentina"
        }
        ...
        ]
}
```

and

```
{
    "matches":
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "team1_id": 1,
            "team2_id": 2,
        }
        ...
        ]
}
```

Using AngularJS how can I get the value from another JSON file. Is there something similar to SQL Joins?

I need to display the Match Details as

> Match 1 Brazil vs Argentina

Where "team1_id" refers to id in "teams" JSON.

Comment: This is not a real question, just basic programming stuff. You're asking us to write your code here.

Comment: I can't find a question anywhere in your question?

Comment: Sorry. I am new to JSON. I wanted to know how we can get the value from another JSON file. Is there something similar to SQL Joins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a map for your teams:

```
$scope.teamsById = {};
for (var i : 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
    var team = teams[i];
    $scope.teamsById[team.id] = team;
}
```

And then in your template:

```
<div ng-repeat="match in matches">
    Match {{ match.id }} : {{ teamsById[match.team1_id] }} vs. {{ teamsById[match.team2_id] }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet. This worked. 
Added .name
Match {{ match.id }} : {{ teamsById[match.team1_id].name }} vs. {{ teamsById[match.team2_id].name }}